# How to use Tensorboard to create histogram of acitvations with Keras functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I use the Keras functional API to create the following network:

```
input = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(input)
tf.summary.histogram(name="conv1", data=x)
x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
tf.summary.histogram(name="conv2", data=x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(x)
tf.summary.histogram(name="dense1", data=x)
x = Dense(units=num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
tf.summary.histogram(name="demse1", data=x)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
```

I used `tf.summary.histogram` to extract information regarding the activations of different layers. However, the layer's activation histograms do not appear in Tensorboard.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use tensorboard callback to get histogram.

```
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir='logs', histogram_freq=1, profile_batch = 0
)

model.fit(x,y, epochs = 5, callbacks = tensorboard_callback)
```

For complete documentation see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard)

Tensorboard Histogram -

[image: model]

Comment: This does not show how to create historgrams for the networks activations.

Comment: For each layer in my neural network I have biases, kernels (weights), preactivations, and activations. Your image only shows bias and kernel information. How can I additionally plot histograms for activations?

Comment: There are no values stored inside activations to visualize. It's just a function to calculate the activation values.

Comment: I know. But it should be possible to use a callback to create a histogram of activations for the current batch at the end of an epoch.

Comment: Despite the fact that `tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` says that it does "activation histograms" in the documentation, it doesn't actually compute these. See the following TensorFlow issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42027 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39755

Comment: i second that - says it's there but it's not